Maximum probability that F(x)=G(x), if F(x),G(x) are non equal polynomials with degree no larger than 6.
So, there are two polynomials $F(y), G(y)$ which are not identical. Maximum degree of polynomials is 6. If probable values of polynomials are $y={1,2,…,n}$ with $n=100$, then

what is the maximum probability that $F(x)=G(x)$ if they are not identical?
How should we choose n so that the probability is no larger than 0.001?

My solution:

So, if they are not identical then that follows that if we define random variables X=F(y) and Y=G(y) are independent. For any possible outcome the probability would be 1/n=1/100. In order for both of the outcome be equal then the probability would be $P(X=Y)=P(X|Y=X) \cap P(Y|X=Y) = \frac{1}{100}\cdot \frac{1}{100}=0.0001$
So, going by the same logic: $P(X=Y)=\frac{1}{n^2}=0.001 \implies 10\sqrt{10}$

I know that my soluyion is inclrrect, because I don’t know where the degree of polynomial comes in.

Why if they are not identical then F(y) and G(y) are independent(also over what probability space?) Also if the question is over the reals and rhe cooficents are chosen randomly from [0,1] the probability is zero, do you mean maybe over some finite field?

What is a "probable value"?
